# How two join multiple tables with multiple conditions in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

```
select d.field_value as name,a.mobile,c.balance,a.created_at from users as a inner join user_profiles as b on a.id = b.user_id
inner join wallets as c on c.user_profile_id = b.id
left join profile_details as d on d.user_id = a.id where d.field_name = "name" and c.balance > 0 order by a.id desc;
```

**This is my query and i need to write in sqlalchemy, i have model with all mentioned tables and proper columns.**
**Thanks for yours all efforts and time spent here.**

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. I've some links to be referred.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins).

How to join multiple tables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326052/sqlalchemy-join-to-retrieve-data-from-multiple-tables).

How to select only few columns from the query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133774/how-can-i-select-only-one-column-using-sqlalchemy).

Left and/or right outer join using sqlalchemy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400307/right-outer-join-in-sqlalchemy)

I think now you may be able to solve your problem. Hope this helps.